# Windows Form drawn ellipse Select and Delete Particularly selected

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I have drawn Some Ellipses on Windows Form.

Is it Possible for 'c# Window Form' to  'mouse click' on an ellipse and to delete it?..

---

Code from Comments

```
public void DrawCircle_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); 
    Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics(); 
    gr.DrawEllipse(pen, 40, 45, 20, 20); 
    Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);  
    Graphics gr1 = this.CreateGraphics(); 
    gr.DrawEllipse(pen2, 30, 25, 38, 20); 
    Pen pen3 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); 
    Graphics gr2 = this.CreateGraphics(); 
    gr.DrawEllipse(pen3, 35, 36, 68, 15); 
    Pen pen4 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); 
    Graphics gr3 = this.CreateGraphics(); 
    gr.DrawEllipse(pen4, 50, 60, 67, 35); 
}
```

Comment: can you please post your code

Comment: public void DrawCircle_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen, 40, 45, 20, 20);
            Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr1 = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen2, 30, 25, 38, 20);
            Pen pen3 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr2 = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen3, 35, 36, 68, 15);
            Pen pen4 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3); Graphics gr3 = this.CreateGraphics(); gr.DrawEllipse(pen4, 50, 60, 67, 35);
        }

Comment: Paste your code in your Question

Comment: Rather edit your question and put that code there

Comment: i don't have any code to delete but i have drawn ellipses

Comment: Arnald, why have you rolled back my edit?!

Comment: @Anand please dont rollback edit ..

Comment: give me Example on MouseHover Event invoked while Drawn particular Ellipse select and delete

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible.

I assume that you know the positions and dimensions of the ellipses and have them stored in a list. Then you can use the [MouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousedown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and iterate through the ellipses. How to check, if a point is in an ellipse, can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse) for example.

If you found a clicked ellipse remove it from your list and repaint everything.

Update:
To your code. You dont need to call CreateGraphics all the time. The graphics object is given in the PaintEventArgs (e.Graphics). Also you dont need to create a pen every time.

```
public void DrawCircle_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
    using(Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
    {
        gr.DrawEllipse(pen, 40, 45, 20, 20);
        gr.DrawEllipse(pen2, 30, 25, 38, 20); 
        gr.DrawEllipse(pen3, 35, 36, 68, 15); 
        gr.DrawEllipse(pen4, 50, 60, 67, 35); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this demo, well there are fairly much work. It's just a demo because there are still many features lacked and also the *memory leakage* problem is not ensured to not occur. Drawing some thing directly using some methods of `Graphics` object won't help you support some interaction (like hittesting). You have to draw a `GraphicsPath` or a `Region` using the methods `FillPath` or `FillRegion`. In this demo, I used `GraphicsPath`, is has 2 interesting methods to help us implement hittesting which are `IsVisible` and `IsOutlineVisible`, in this case we just use `IsVisible`. Now is the code for you:

```
public class Ellipse : IDisposable
{
    GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
    RectangleF rect;
    public Ellipse(Point center, float rx, float ry)
    {
        Center = center;
        RadiusX = rx;
        RadiusY = ry;
        Visible = true;
        rect = new RectangleF(Center.X - RadiusX, Center.Y - RadiusY, RadiusX * 2, RadiusY * 2);
        gp.AddEllipse(rect);
        BackColor = Color.Green;
        SelectedBackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
    public event EventHandler Click;
    public event EventHandler MouseEnter;
    public event EventHandler MouseLeave;
    Point center;
    float rx, ry;
    Control canvas;
    bool entered;
    bool visible;
    Color backColor;
    Color borderColor;
    Color selectedColor;
    bool selected;
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set
        {
            if (selected != value)
            {
                selected = value;
                if (canvas != null) canvas.Invalidate(Rectangle.Ceiling(rect));
            }
        }
    }
    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return visible; }
        set
        {
            if (visible != value)
            {
                visible = value;
                if(canvas != null) canvas.Invalidate(Rectangle.Ceiling(rect));
            }
        }
    }
    public Control Canvas
    {
        get { return canvas; }
        set
        {
            if (canvas != value)
            {
                if(canvas != null) DetachCanvas(canvas);
                if (value != null)
                {
                    AttachCanvas(value);
                    value.Invalidate(Rectangle.Ceiling(rect));
                }                    
                canvas = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public Point Center
    {
        get { return center; }
        set
        {
            if (center != value)
            {
                int dx = value.X - center.X;
                int dy = value.Y - center.Y;
                rect.Offset(dx, dy);
                center = value;
                gp.Reset();
                gp.AddEllipse(rect);
                if (canvas != null) canvas.Invalidate(Rectangle.Ceiling(rect));
            }
        }
    }
    public float RadiusX
    {
        get { return rx; }
        set
        {
            if (rx != value)
            {
                rect.Width = rx * 2;
                rx = value;
                gp.Reset();
                gp.AddEllipse(rect);
                if (canvas != null) canvas.Invalidate(Rectangle.Ceiling(rect));
            }
        }
    }
    public float RadiusY
    {
        get { return ry; }
        set
        {
            if (ry != value)
            {
                rect.Height = ry * 2;
                ry = value;
                gp.Reset();
                gp.AddEllipse(rect);
                if (canvas != null) canvas.Invalidate(Rectangle.Ceiling(rect));
            }
        }
    }
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return borderColor; }
        set
        {
            if (borderColor != value)
            {
                borderColor = value;
                if (canvas != null) canvas.Invalidate(Rectangle.Ceiling(rect));
            }
        }
    }
    public Color SelectedBackColor
    {
        get { return selectedColor; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedColor != value)
            {
                selectedColor = value;
                if (canvas != null) canvas.Invalidate(Rectangle.Ceiling(rect));
            }
        }
    }
    public Color BackColor
    {
        get { return backColor; }
        set
        {
            if (backColor != value)
            {
                backColor = value;
                if (canvas != null) canvas.Invalidate(Rectangle.Ceiling(rect));
            }
        }
    }
    private void Render(Graphics g)
    {            
        using(Pen p = new Pen(BorderColor))
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(selected ? SelectedBackColor : BackColor))
        {
            SmoothingMode sm = g.SmoothingMode;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.FillPath(b, gp);
            g.DrawPath(p, gp);
            g.SmoothingMode = sm;
        }
    }
    private void CanvasPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Visible) Render(e.Graphics);
    }
    private void CanvasMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var cv = sender as Control;
        if (gp.IsVisible(e.Location))
        {
            var handler = MouseEnter;
            if (handler != null && Visible)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            entered = true;
        }
        else if (entered)
        {
            var handler = MouseLeave;
            if (handler != null && Visible)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            entered = false;
        }
    }
    private void CanvasMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
        var cv = sender as Control;
        if (gp.IsVisible(e.Location))
        {
            var handler = Click;                
            if (handler != null && Visible) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    private void AttachCanvas(Control canvas)
    {
        canvas.Paint += CanvasPaint;
        canvas.MouseMove += CanvasMouseMove;
        canvas.MouseClick += CanvasMouseClick;
    }
    private void DetachCanvas(Control canvas)
    {
        canvas.Paint -= CanvasPaint;
        canvas.MouseMove -= CanvasMouseMove;
        canvas.MouseClick -= CanvasMouseClick;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Visible = false;
        if (Canvas != null) Canvas.Invalidate(Rectangle.Ceiling(rect));
        Canvas = null;
        gp.Dispose();             
    }        
}
```

**Usage**: I implemented only 3 events: `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave` and `Click`. These events are very similar to the events we use with normal control. Here is the demo code for you to test, it will render the ellipse on a form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        var e = new Ellipse(new Point(400, 400), 100, 100) { Canvas = this };
        e.MouseEnter += (s, ev) => {
            e.BackColor = Color.Red;
        };
        e.MouseLeave += (s, ev) => {
            e.BackColor = Color.Green;
        };
        e.Click += (s, ev) => {
            e.Visible = false; //Hide the ellipse
        };
    }
}
```

Note that you can create your own class for other shapes.

**UPDATE**: I updated the `Ellipse` class with some modification to avoid memory leakage, to delete the ellipse you just need to call `Dispose`, it will delete the ellipse and you can't use it anymore, for your requirement with a `List<Ellipse>`, try this:

```
//You have to handle `Ellipse.Click` to set the `Selected` manually, this is by design
//do this for every ellipses
Ellipse selectedEllipse;
//Use this handler for all the Click event of your ellipses
private void Ellipse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){  
  var ellipse = sender as Ellipse;
  if(ellipse == selectedEllipse) return;
  if(selectedEllipse != null) selectedEllipse.Selected = false;
  ellipse.Selected = true;
  selectedEllipse = ellipse;
}
List<Ellipse> ellipses = ...; //this is your List<Ellipse>
for(int i = ellipses.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  if(ellipses[i].Selected){
    ellipses[i].Dispose();
    ellipses.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```

The code to handle the `Ellipse.Click` event for every `Ellipse` can be modified to allow **multiple selected**. That's why it's not hard-coded to be selected when begin clicked.

Comment: Thanks sir its Working Properly..but i want to delete from Button Click.

Comment: @Anand just handle the button `Click` and set the `Visible` of the `Ellipse` to `false`.

Comment: Sir i want Example that Ellipse List<> if select Particular Ellipse and Click delete button it will go from List <> How to do that.

Comment: @Anand I updated the code of `Ellipse` class for new requirement, you should copy it again (the old code won't work) and see the update part with a simple code to delete all the selected ellipses in the `List<Ellipse>`

Comment: Where i would put this Updated your Code. Form1 : Form or Ellipse.cs

Answer (score 0):

**try it !**

```
 Bitmap Painting;
 Pen Pen_Drawing;
 Graphics Graph_Drawing;

 Pen_Drawing.Dispose();
 Graph_Drawing.Dispose();
 Painting.Dispose();

 Painting = new Bitmap(500, 500);
 Pen_Drawing = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(95, 158, 160), 1f);
 Graph_Drawing = Graphics.FromImage(Painting);
```